# Group objects in a list using the Stream API

Tags: java, java-stream

Imagine we have the POJO class `Item`:

```
class Item {
    private String key;
    private String $value;

    // constructors, getters & setters
}
```

And in our main class we have a `List` containing some of those items. How can I group all Items with the same `key` using the Stream API?

I found that `Collectors.groupingBy` is more or less what I'm looking for, but it returns a Map, and I need to preserve the item `List` order.

For example, imagine the list is as follows:

```
List [
    Item { key1, value1 },
    Item { key2, value2 },
    Item { key2, value3 }
]
```

I'd expect a returning value like (and only like) the following:

```
List [
    List [
        Item { key1, value1 }
    ], 
    List [
        Item { key2, value2 },
        Item { key2, value3 }
    ]
]
```

I don't know if it helps knowing why I want to do this (maybe there's a better way), but I want to end up having a List of another object that contains the key and a list of all items with that key:

```
List [
    AnotherObject {
        key1,
         List [
            Item { key1, value1 }
        ]
    },

    AnotherObject {
        key2,
         List [
            Item { key2, value2 },
            Item { key2, value3 }
        ]
    }
]
```

Being AnotherObject another POJO class:

```
class AnotherObject {
    private String key;
    private List<Item> $items;

    // constructors, getters & setters
}
```

Comment: `AnotherObject` being a `Map` ?

Comment: So you want a `Map<K,List<V>>` but by another name? And you want to preserve the order of the keys? (Note: `LinkedHashMap` preserves insertion order) - since the source of `Collectors.groupingBy` is part of the Java distribution, you could start with that and adjust it a bit.

Comment: @YassinHajaj I just added the AnotherObject class to the original post.

Comment: Would you want the following items to be grouped or kept apart? `List [
    Item { key2, value2 },
    Item { key1, value1 },
    Item { key2, value3 }
]`

Comment: @Hans I'm not sure I understand. My final goal is to create a list of container objects `AnotherObject` that will have an attribute with the key and another attribute with a list of all `Item` objects with that key. I used that list as an example of an intermediary step because I think I can do it from there, but maybe there was another way to do this without having to go through that step.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I don't know how to adjust the Java distribution but seems unnecessary for something simple (I guess) like what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just map your Map entry returned by `groupBy` to your AnotherObject.

```
List<AnotherObject> result = items.stream()
     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getKey, LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.toList()))
     .entrySet()
     .stream()
     .map(e -> new AnotherObject(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Is the order guaranteed once you convert the stream into a Set with `entrySet`?

Comment: The order is same as you processing your list. As it is backed by a LinkedHashMap.

Comment: The IDE complains about Item::getKey not being referenceable from a static context and ::new is not resolvable.

Comment: Make the correct import and retry. Also create your getters method and constructors. I tried and tested. It works

Comment: And don't reference with `Item::getKey` unless `getKey` is static use the item's variable name instead e.g. someMethod(I -> I.getKey())`

Comment: No, `Item::getKey` is correct. It's a method reference that will be applied to every `item` instance.

Comment: Perfect, but `e.getValues()` should be `e.getValue()`. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be using the `toMap` collector:

```
Collection<AnotherObject> resultSet = items.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Item::getKey,
                    f -> new AnotherObject(f.getKey(),
                            new ArrayList<>(Collections.singletonList(f))),
                    (left, right) -> {
                        left.get$items().addAll(right.get$items());
                        return left;
                    }, LinkedHashMap::new)).values();
```